# ZIP file gets corrupted during upload to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, zip, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm using node.js and knox's putFile to upload a zip file to S3. The original zip opens fine, the zip download from S3 is corrupt.

Here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
var client = knox.createClient({
    key: 'MY KEY HERE', 
    secret: 'MY SECRET HERE', 
    bucket: 'MY BUCKET HERE'
});

var filename = 'example.zip';

var req = client.putFile(filename, filename, { 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' }, function(err, res){
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('moved '+filename+' to s3');
    }
    else {
        console.log('failed to move to s3');
    }
});
```

This is the output I get when trying to fix the zip file using zip in terminal on OSX

```
> zip -F remote.zip --out fixed-remote.zip
Fix archive (-F) - assume mostly intact archive
zip warning: bad archive - missing end signature
zip warning: (If downloaded, was binary mode used?  If not, the
zip warning:  archive may be scrambled and not recoverable)
zip warning: Can't use -F to fix (try -FF)
zip error: Zip file structure invalid (remote.zip)

> zip -FF remote.zip --out fixed-remote.zip
zip warning: Missing end (EOCDR) signature - either this archive is not readable or the end is damaged
> Is this a single-disk archive?  (y/n): y
Assuming single-disk archive
[LISTS ALL FILES COPIED HERE]
zip warning: no end of stream entry found: awesome-file.jpg
zip warning: rewinding and scanning for later entries
```

I'm totally lost as to why this would be happening. Almost seems as though the last couple bytes aren't being sent by knox, but that's a total rookie guess.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I think it may be an issue with generating the ZIP file, not the upload. I tried uploading zip file generated by the OSX Zip Utility and it work fine every time. I'll dig into this a little deeper. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the call to `#putFile()` set all the headers correctly? Everything look OK on the S3 end?

Comment: The incident doesn't seem isolated to you Chris.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=341456

Are you using Express at all/

Comment: here are the headers that are sent:

{ 'Content-Length': 7251987,
  'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
  'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' }

Not using express at all.

Answer (score 2):

Convenience APIs such as putFile and putStream currently do not work as expected with buckets in regions other than US Standard without explicitly specify the region option.

Make sure to add your region:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox#region

```
var client = knox.createClient({
    key: 'MY KEY HERE', 
    secret: 'MY SECRET HERE', 
    bucket: 'MY BUCKET HERE',
    region: 'us-standard'
});
```

Seems to work? File sizes were the same for me:
**Output:**

```
node aws.js 
{ Name: 'MYBUCKET',
  Prefix: '',
  Marker: '',
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  IsTruncated: false,
  Contents: 
   [ { Key: 'hudson_out.jpg',
       LastModified: Wed May 29 2013 12:38:50 GMT-0400 (EDT),
       ETag: '"996f46db285c900f3e1596d484a72fb4"',
       Size: 1690706,
       Owner: [Object],
       StorageClass: 'STANDARD' } ] }
moved hudson_out.jpg to s3
```

ls -la hudson_out.jpg 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 (stuff) 1690706 31 Aug  2012 hudson_out.jpg